# Karma - Unexpected token when including an html file

Tags: karma-runner

I'm trying to include an simple html file in my karma config file to access the html elements from my javascript files and test this with jasmine in karma.

But I'm getting always an **Unexpected token <** error. I saw in an webcast that it is possible to include html files, but I don't know why it doesn't works with my configuration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need use the [html2js preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-html2js-preprocessor) (or the [ng-html2js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) preprocessor if using AngularJS). See the preprocessor description for how it works.

Since Karma 0.10, the html2js preprocessor is shipped with Karma and configured by default:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'templates/*.html'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.html': ['html2js']
    }
  });
};
```

Then you can access the html content as JS string:

```
var elm = $(__html__['templates/x.html'])
```

The error you are getting means that the HTML files are not preprocessed. By default, all HTML files under the `basePath` are preprocessed, so maybe your HTML files are somewhere else, in which case you need to put them in the `preprocessors` config explicitly. Share your `karma.conf.js` if you need more help.

Comment: This is not the proper way to do that... If you want to use a static file you have to turn off the `include` flag by its pattern.

Comment: In this way, you don't have to deal with async, you can easily write your tests synchronously.

Comment: That said, you can use "include": false, sure.

Answer (score 1):

By karma config you have to register every file your want to use in your tests. You can do that by adding patterns to your `files` array in your config.

A file pattern looks like this:

```
files: [
    {
        pattern: 'test/unit/*.js',
        watched: true, //watching file modifications for test autorun
        included: true, //included as <script src="..."> in the runner html file
        served: true //used by tests (the test server should serve it)
    }
]
```

You can use short pattern syntax:

```
files: [
    'test/unit/*.js'
]
```

This means exactly the same as the previous pattern.

If you don't want to use your file in your test included as `<script src="file.js"></script>`, then you have use `included: false` and load the file from within your tests via AJAX. Be aware that you should use relative urls for that, because the domain of the test server can always change...

The pattern order is important too, it uses reverse overriding:

```
files: [
     {pattern: '*.js', included: true}
     {pattern: '*.js', included: false}
]
```

In this case every js file will be included, so the first pattern overrides the second.

For example by html files:

**karma config:**

```
files: [
     {pattern: 'bootstrap.js', included: true}
     {pattern: 'x.html', included: false}
]
```

**bootstrap.js:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', '/base/x.html', false);
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr.status, xhr.responseText); //200, '<html content>'
```

The URI always has a `/base` prefix because Karma stores its own `index.html` and js files on the top level, so it needs a subfolder. If you want to find out what URIs are served, you can use this code:

```
var servedUris = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files);
```

I wrote some basic `fs` stuff to support sync read by Yadda: https://github.com/acuminous/yadda/blob/master/lib/shims/karma-fs.js You might be able to move it to a different project extend it, and use `fs` instead of AJAX in browser. At least that's how I would do it with Browserify.

Comment: Thanks for providing a hack free solution but I'm getting 404's on the AJAX request. In `karma.conf.js` I have `basePath: '', files: [
      {
        pattern: 'spec/fixture.svg',
        included: false,
        served: true
      }]` and in my test I have `xhr.open('GET', 'spec/fixture.svg', false)`. Is there a way to see the karma server endpoints?

Comment: Aha. I didn't think **`base`** was the root directory. You could improve your answer by making that clear.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Okay.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Done.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a simple patch to the `lib/middleware/karma.js` file in my Karma installation. It uses an extension `.literal` to denote "just echo the entire file onto the page". I've always found it strange that Karma doesn't have an inbuilt way to do this. My way is certainly not brilliantly-constructed but it might be good enough for you.

With this you can just have in your karma.conf.js:

```
// ...
files: [
   "path/to/my_html.literal", // Echoed directly onto the page
   "path/to/other.js",        // Normal behaviour
   // ...
],
```

My nested `scriptTags` function (inside `createKarmaMiddleware`) just looks like this:

```js
var scriptTags = files.included.map(function(file) {
  var filePath = file.path;
  var fileExt = path.extname(filePath);

  // Include .literal files directly into the body of the HTML.
  if (filePath.match(/.literal$/)) {
     var fs = require("fs");
     return fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");
  }

  // ...
```

The diff is here: https://github.com/amagee/karma/commit/c09346a71fc27c94cc212a2bd88b23def19ec3a4