# Can Karma simply serve html resource files without transforming them?

Tags: karma-runner

Additional files required by tests, like test fixtures in html files, shall be served by the web server integrated into the Karma test runner. It has been asked before how to do this, like in

[Karma - Unexpected token when including an html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586074/karma-unexpected-token-when-including-an-html-file)

and the answer was to preprocess them into a script via html2js. I do not understand the reason to do so, **I simply want the karma web server to serve the file normally**. How can this be accomplished?

If this is not possible, what is the benefit on transforming html resources into js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the file in the `karma.conf.js` with `included: false` flag.

```
files: [
  {pattern: 'templates/*.html', included: false}
],
```

After that you can load those html fragments with your favourite ajax tool...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', '/base/templates/xxx.html', false);
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr.status, xhr.responseText); //200, "<html content>"
```

By default those files are with `included: true` flag... Karma creates script tags from includables...

Comment: There is a typo. It should be "..., included: false}"

Comment: @Marat I use to check the code I publish, maybe `include` works or used to work as well. I am not sure, I did not play with gui tests nowadays.